# Rails chomp method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, chomp

I have the following line of code in my model method.

```
subjectsinlist='['
subjectlist.subjects.each do |subject|
     subjectsinlist=subjectsinlist+subject.subject_code+', '
end
subjectsinlist.chomp(', ')
subjectsinlist+="]"
```

An example of the strings to append are:

```
CPE205 CPE206 CPE301 CPE302 HW0210
```

I am expecting the results to hence be:

```
[CPE205, CPE206, CPE301, CPE302, HW0210]
```

But instead I am getting:

```
[CPE205, CPE206, CPE301, CPE302, HW0210, ]
```

The `chomp` method does not seem to be working.
Any advice on why that happened would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chomp returns a new string, see [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/chomp)

but u have to assign the new string to a variable:

```
subjectsinlist = subjectsinlist.chomp(', ')
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have a clue why it didn't work since I did the exact same thing in console and received the correct output.

Comment: because in your model you forgot to assign subjectsinlist.chomp(', ') to a variable. if you do it like this subjectsinlist = subjectsinlist.chomp(', ') the new string returned from chomp() will be assigned to subjectsinlist :) In console using subjectsinlist.chomp(', ') will give you the correct output but it only renders that output.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can also use the chomp! method to modify the string in place and avoid reassigning the variable. Example: subjectsinlist.chomp!(', ')

Answer (score 2):

This can do the trick:

```
codes = "[#{subjectlist.subjects.map(&:subject_code).join(', ')}]"
```

Some explanations:

- The `map(&:subject_code)` will call the method `subject_code` on each element of the array returned by `subjectlist.subjects`
- The `join(', ')` will put ', ' (coma-space) **between** each element of the array (except the last one).

**The `join` method is what you need here** ;-)

Comment: Just tried it and this worked perfectly while being neater but I would have to accept the answer on chomp since he answered specific to what I asked for. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, using `chomp` is kinda wrong since we don't want to iterate on each x elements of the array. We just want to iterate on the x-1 elements (all except the last one). This is why `join` fits totally here.

Comment: Thanks. I am using this as well and your explanation was really clear. Being new to ruby I just basically tried whatever I knew to get it to work. So I really appreciate you introducing to me a new method.

Answer (score 1):

`subjectsinlist = '[' + subjectlist.subjects.join(', ') + ']'`

That should work.

The reason chomp isn't working for you is because it returns a new string, rather than changing the existing string: http://apidock.com/ruby/String/chomp

Comment: Tried this out but I wanted a specific attribute of the list. This is a much cleaner way of putting it though so thanks!

Comment: `subjectlist.subjects` will return Subject objects, which you are trying to join. (chomp before your edit), but we need the `subject_code` attribute of each subjects ...

Comment: Yep, in the initial code it wasn't immediately clear as the formatting was bad: Your solution is correct.